# Retrieving SQL query behind channel entries tag

Tags: expressionengine

EE 2.5.5

I'd like to find the exact SQL query that is run by a channel entries tag, I've tried displaying the database queries by I can't see any related to running a channel entries tag.

I've simplified the template and now just have the tag in it:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel" 
disable="member_data|comments|trackbacks|categories" dynamic="no"     require_entry="yes"}
  {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: The query you are looking for should definitely be present when displaying the database queries.  Perhaps you could post the result and we could help you find it.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm understanding what you need.
Try using `{total_results}` as opposed to `{total_entries}` or are you looking for something like `SELECT COUNT(entry_id) FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE status="open"`

**Edit:**

If your output profiler is enabled in the backend you should be able to see something like the image below. In the orange text you'll see build query function I'm speaking of.

[image]
[image]

Comment: no, I'm not really interested in which fields are returned (total_entries was just a placeholder), I'd like to find the exact query that's run, it doesn't seem to be as simple as the select you've suggested as the number of results doesn't match.

Comment: By the sounds of it you've already enabled template debugging in the backend. You may want to look at the queries associated with build_sql_query(). You'll see one that looks like "SELECT channel_id FROM exp_channels WHERE  channel_name = 'mychannel'" and look at the ones after that. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: I was expecting a query like "SELECT channel_id ...", but there isn't one. Where would I find 'build_sql_query'?

Comment: Ah, I've removed 'require_entry="yes"' and it is displaying the expected query!

Comment: Glad to see you've resolved it! If you have template debugging on, click the queries tab and search for build_sql_query you'll see them. For your questions purpose it'd make more sense to search for your channel first.

Comment: there is no 'build_sql_query', the info under the Queries tab is pure sql so how could that be under there?

Comment: I added some images to my original post that hopefully help what I was saying make more sense.